# How to get bill/service-tag of old laptop

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron, anti-theft

I can't find my Dell laptop bill, and I also don't remember the service tag number. Two years ago my Dell Inspiron N1050 laptop was stolen but all of sudden I got a call from police that they found the thief. To get my laptop back I need to provide the service tag. The police are asking me about the billing details to prove ownership, but the guy from which I bought the laptop did not write anything about the details of the laptop. Is there any way for me to determine what the service tag, or otherwise prove my ownership?

Comment: How about contacting the person who sold the laptop to you and let him witness he did so to the police. But dude, I don't think this question belongs here...

Comment: If you didn't keep the records, how are we suppose to help, if you purchased it through Dell it was all sent you in both digital and physical copies.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the person who sold you the laptop, and requesting he contact Dell to see if they can provide him with a copy of the receipt?  Did the person you bought the laptop from register it with Dell when he bought it?  Are we to assume that you did not register it with Dell when you bought it second hand?

Comment: since it is a dell, did you ever register on the dell website to download the drivers?

Comment: the only way it seems is to get a copy of bill of sale from the shopkeeper and call up dell customer care. That might help you

Comment: Did you ever register it on the Dell website? Your service tag(s) can be accessed there.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the person wiped clean the laptop, you probably have personal identification on the laptop (is the windows user account your name, for example?).

If you bought the computer from a 1st party, or installed from scratch, how about:

1. Open your "Computer" folder (Start menu -> Computer)
2. Display the file menu (hit ALT to show it)

[image]

3. Select 'About Windows'
4. See who the machine was licensed to.

[image]

This is the name that was entered on the first time the laptop was started up. It's not the user or account name, and it's not the computer name, it's the Windows licensee name. For me, I put in my last name. I think the setup prompt says, "*Who is this version of Microsoft Windows licensed to?*" or something like that.

Unless the operating system was reinstalled (or unless it was pretended to be reinstalled using certain command-line tools meant for OEMs), this name would never change, even if your original windows user was deleted and a new one created.

Comment: This seems like the most likely method to be successful.

Comment: Unless the thief reinstalled the OS, unfortunately. But even if he merely deleted the original account and created a new one, this method should still work! Let's hope he was lazy or incompetent.